# How long does it take Macrocarpa wood to naturally weather to a silver colour?

Tags: wood

If I were to use Macrocarpa wood as cladding, I am aware that it would develop a natural silver colour over time if left untreated. However, I am wondering how long it would normally take to naturally develop said silver colour?

Thanks in advance.